# Zend studio creates empty index.php file

Tags: php, git, zend-studio

Wehenever i create a new project in zend studio (New -> local php project) on an existing directory (code checked out with git) it tries to make an empty index.php file (i already have an index.php so zend studio just replaces it with an empty file). I can't seem to find the option to disable this.

Platform: Mac OSX 10.7.3

Zend studio version: 9.0.1.v20111214366 ? ie the latest version

Comment: May be its something to do with default project template

Comment: @Shiplu this is something i'd might consider, i can't find this option though.

Comment: @lazy badger: nope this is the right order, git doesn't let you checkout in a directory that has content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be default zend studio behavior, can seem to be fixed unless Zend decided to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

With Zend Studio 9 you need to go File -> New -> Project which will popup with the project template list. Open up the PHP option and select "PHP Project from Existing Directory". That will take you through a flow that doesn't overwrite the index.php file.

Alternatively you can directly create a new project checked out from GIT using the interface.

Answer (score -1):

Undo local zend changes - `git checkout HEAD index.php`

Comment: I already do this each time (well actually i reset the index file), i want to prevent doing this by stopping zend studio creating the index when it already exists.